# Synchronization Context

Tags: c#, async-await

I understand `.ConfigureAwait(false)` means the continuation does not have to be on the same thread as when entered.

So I wonder what Synchronization Context will I get back in someUIButton_click.

```
static async void someUIButton_click()
{
   await T1();
   // Am I sur to be on the UI thread ?
}

static async Task T1() => await doSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)
```

Context : C#, winforms, .Net 4.7

Comment: Yes, but why you are doing that is more the mystery

Comment: No, it is not the same thread. You can check this by printing the thread ID. However, this thread has the the same context as the thread before the await. Hence you can do everything that the thread before the await could do. After an awaited ConfigureAwait you cannot be certain that it has the same context. as before the await.

Answer (score 4):

## SynchronizationContext and the Execution Context

Every thread has a context associated with it, this is also known as the *Current Context* and these contexts can be shared across threads. The `ExecutionContext` contains relevant metadata of the current environment or context in which the program is in execution.

The `SynchronizationContext` represents an abstraction that defines the location where your application's code is executed. `SynchronizationContext` is a representation of the current environment that our code is running in, it provides a way to queue a unit of work to a context. 
The `SynchronizationContext` has a context associated with it and in different situations and different frameworks may represent different things. For example

- Winform Apps – `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`
- WPF APS – `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`
- The default SynchronizationContext - Default (ThreadPool) `SynchronizationContext`
- ASP.Net - `AspNetSynchronizationContext`

## How await uses SynchronisationContext’s

*Async/await* is just compiler magic to make it easier to compose asynchronous stuff (it does not make your code run asynchronously), all it does when it sees an `await` is splits your method up into a *State Machine* and when the thing you are *awaiting* finishes executing, the state machine is resumed and your code continues running. Resuming execution is called the *continuation*.

A feature of the `await` keyword is that it captures the current `SynchronizationContext` before it runs the asynchronous operation, then it will post the *continuation* to that `SynchronizationContext`, meaning if you are on the *UI Thread* when you `await`, once it has finished running then your code will continue execution on the *UI Thread* (which is called *Offloading*)

## ConfigureAwait()

All `ConfigureAwait(false)` does is configures the task so that *continuation* after the `await` does not have to be run in the caller context. This can have several benefits, one of them is a small performance gain, and more controversially stopping deadlocks in certain situations.

## The Answer

Every time you call `await` it creates a *State Machine* to do the wonders of the *Async Await Pattern* and sets up a *continuation*.

Just because you have `ConfigureAwait` set to `false` nested in another `await` (*State Machine*) doesn't change the original call which is set to continue on the calling *Synchronization Context* (if applicable).

***Side note*** : `someUIButton_click` is running unobserved and you should have appropriate error checking

## Update

> So that means that I can do whatever I want in `T1` as long it does not
>   interacts with some UI components

You are "seemingly" free to access *UI components* from both `someUIButton_click` and `T1` however, with the exception that **after** the `await` in `T1` you have configured the task so that the continuation does not need to return to the calling context. Accessing the a `UI` component here will likely cause you problems.

So what about after the `await` in `someUIButton_click`?

Well in that case, task has (by default) captured the current context (presumably your *UI thread*), and the continuation will continue on that context. Each nested await is a different case, and the calling `await` (state machine) gets to choose which context it continues on

Comment: Thank you, So that means that I can do whatever I want in T1 as long it does not interracts with some UI components.

Comment: I am confused...
Does that mean that *after* await T1() in someUIButton_click() I am not sure to be on UI thread ? meaning that interacting with UI component *may* crash since the current thread is no longer the thread used to create these UI compoents.

Comment: Thank you from Paris Michael. That clarifies my understanding.